# RecyclerView doesn't always show data (just in few cases and then even wrong data)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some problems with the RecyclerView in Android Studio. After updating Android Studio it doesn't work anymore. It just shows data in few cases but these data doesn't belong to the correct point. I hope you can help me as I have no idea what went wrong. I will post the source code of the adapter as I think that the problem lays here.
Thank you very much even if you can't help.

```
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SatzungAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SatzungAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ArrayList<String> mDataset;
    private int expandedPosition = -1;
    public String Regeln[] = {HERE IS THE DATA STORED};

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView txtHeader;
        public TextView txtFooter;
        LinearLayout ExpandArea;
        public TextView txtExpand;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            ExpandArea = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ExpandArea);
            txtExpand = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpandTxt);
        }
    }


    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public SatzungAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public SatzungAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.satzung_text, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        vh.itemView.setOnClickListener(SatzungAdapter.this);
        vh.itemView.setTag(vh);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SatzungAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final String name = mDataset.get(position);
        holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));
        if (position == expandedPosition) {
            holder.ExpandArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.ExpandArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //holder.txtFooter.setText("Footer: " + mDataset.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        String theString = mDataset.get(holder.getPosition());

        // Check for an expanded view, collapse if you find one
        if (expandedPosition >= 0) {
            int prev = expandedPosition;
            notifyItemChanged(prev);
        }
        // Set the current position to "expanded"
        expandedPosition = holder.getPosition();
        notifyItemChanged(expandedPosition);
        TextView iv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ExpandTxt);
        iv.setText(Regeln[expandedPosition]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override getItemType(int position)

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't help :-(